# Find the only f=vt that has f(2t)=4f(t)

Tags: calculus

I'm just starting calculus 1 and I don't know how to solve this.  Can someone please help?

The problem below involves linear functions $f(t) = vt + C$. Find the constants v and C.

Find the only $f=vt$ that has $f(2t)=4f(t)$.  show that every $f=\frac{1}{2}at^2$ has this property.

Comment: What is $v$?  A constant?  A function of $t$?

Comment: its velocity.  They don't say in the book so I assume its a constant but not sure.

Comment: I added an update to the description of the problem.  It is under a header that says to find the constants v and C.  Does this help?

Comment: By definition, if $f$ is linear, $f(2t)=2f(t)\ne4f(t)$.

Comment: But then I guess someone needs to tell MIT that their open courseware Calculus book is wrong.  https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/resources/Strang/Edited/Calculus/Calculus.pdf.  Page 13, problem 28.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: there is one exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $v$ is constant: $f(2t) = 4f(t)$ implies $v(2t) = 4(vt)$ and therefore $2vt = 0$.

This yields either $t$ or $v$ must be $0$, but since the equation has to hold for all $t$ this means $v$ must be $0$.

Now let $f(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2$. $f(2t) = \frac{1}{2}a(2t)^2 = \frac{1}{2}a(4t^2) = 4(\frac{1}{2}at^2) = 4f(t)$, regardless of $a$.

Hope this helps!